# How to generate uuid in apache2.2?

Tags: apache, apache2.2

```
#include<apr_uuid.h>
char* gen_UUID()
{
 apr_uuid_t *t;
 char ch[40];
 apr_uuid_get(t);
 apr_uuid_parse(uuid,ch);
}
```

I am getting segmentation fault error.

Comment: now i am able to generate uuid

Comment: Please, tell the SO community about your solution. Otherwise your question would be useless for others to learn from. Thank you.

Comment: how do you able to generate uuid.

Comment: ~char* generate_UUID(request_rec *r)
{
    apr_uuid_t *uuid;
    char uuid_str[40];
    uuid=(apr_uuid_t *)apr_palloc(r->pool,sizeof(apr_uuid_t));
    apr_uuid_get(uuid);
    apr_uuid_format(uuid_str,uuid);
    ap_rprintf(r,"after format %s",uuid_str);
    return uuid_str;
}

Comment: please find my code . Sorry i dont know how to post code in comment.

Comment: The main issue is that you use a buffer that is allocated on the stack and will be no more accessible once you have returned from the function. Solutions : allocate a buffer with apr_palloc() OR declare a buffer in the function that calls gen_UUID() and pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

GENERATE uuiD

```
char* generate_UUID(request_rec *r)
{ 
   apr_uuid_t *uuid; char uuid_str[40]; 
   uuid=(apr_uuid_t *)apr_palloc(r->pool,sizeof(apr_uuid_t));
   apr_uuid_get(uuid); 
   apr_uuid_format(uuid_str,uuid); ap_rprintf(r,"after format %s",uuid_str); 
   return uuid_str; 
}
```